# Creating different charts (especially pi charts) using antdesign in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, pie-chart, antd

In my first ever react app, I'm using [ant.design](https://ant.design) as front-end library. Now I need to create different sort of graphs especially **pie charts** in my app. So I explored components of [ant.design](https://ant.design) but didn't get any good option in this regard.

Is that possible to create charts/graphs especially pie chart using any of antdesign component? If not then what is the best suited solution in this regard?

Comment: You can use other React components, like http://recharts.org/. I don't know about http://ant.design, but it looks like it doesn't have chart components.

Comment: ok thanks, I haven't used recharts.org yet but will give it a look.

Comment: Quite easy to use and good looking, have a look at the pie examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with the Ant team there is [AntV](https://antv.alipay.com/g2/doc/index.html) which is very capable, but does not have React components and (like Ant.Design 6 months ago) only has Chinese documentation. Browsing the docs using Chrome auto-translate works very well, however.

Then there are many JS charting packages with React wrappers:

https://github.com/fraserxu/react-chartist

https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs

http://www.fusioncharts.com/react-charts/#/demos/ex1

...etc.

For a more light-weight React-first solution go with

https://github.com/recharts/recharts

https://github.com/fundkis/reactchart